# How to Get ICCID in flutter without native code. Is this possible?

Tags: flutter

How to Get ICCID in flutter without native code. Is this possible?

pubspec.yaml

```
telephony: ^0.5.0
```

code

```
void getIccid() async {
    TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = await TelephonyInfo().query;

    if (telephonyInfo != null) {
        String iccid = telephonyInfo.iccid ?? "Not available";
        print("ICCID: $iccid");
    } else {
        print("Failed to retrieve telephony information");
    }
}
```

this is not working for my side